# OpenDNS - A Matter of Curiosity

Tags: networking, opendns

Just tonight I have been working on my webserver and suddenly found that I no longer had access to my website (which had been working just fine that very evening). After a lot of messing-around with testing and diagnostics, none of which were able to confirm an actual error, I switched the IPv6 DNS of **2620:0:ccc::2** and **2620:0:ccd::2** to **2001:4860:4860::8844** and **2001:4860:4860::8888** (from OpenDNS to Google) and, lo and behold(!), my website returned.

Looking through the posts on the forum, and the internet in general, I can see that there are a lot of **OD** problems with that service (*eg*: https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000791928-Open-DNS-Blocking-websites-for-no-reason-) and wondered if this was one of them, or if it simply does not like my website for some reason?

For the curious: my <strike>website</strike> webpage is: *insurgent.info*. It is basic, the navigation is <strike>lousy</strike> non-existent, treehuggers are cantankerous (or, at least, this one is) and, yes, this question probably should be somewhere it isn't.

=========================================================================

**Update 16.05.18:** the problem definitely is **not** just DNS service related: just today I had to change the IPv6 service three times (my IPv4 DNS is covered by my ISP, via a DNSSEC-secured IPv4 client-resolver), and each time I was able to browse my webpage once, maybe twice at most, before all my attempts were timing out. The problem got so bad this evening that I was not even able to use my laptop for updates, installing packages, or anything at all involving the internet. I absolutely do not understand what is happening, as the logs for *named* and *httpd* are showing no problems what-so-ever, and both the laptop and the Windows PC are using the same router, with no attacks or other issues in the logs.

I do not have a firewall on the laptop because there is a very comprehensive firewall, and DoS Defence, on the router; plus I have no ports open to the internet except those that have to be, and MySQL has remote connections disabled.

I know for a fact that the website is visible to other people, - the only person who is unable to browse the website is myself; ie: it would appear to be only connections from my fixed IPv4 address and IPv6 subnet which are being blocked, either through a configuration issue or some kind of (automatic?) blacklist on the DNS service side.

Has anyone got any ideas on this, please, as I am completely out of ideas on what else could possibly be causing this issue?

Comment: What replies was OpenDNS sending? Were they SERVFAIL errors? Their actual blocking is usually highly visible (redirects to another site), as long as the domain isn't using DNSSEC.

Comment: Absolutely nothing, - I eventually received a page time-out load failure with Waterfox (Firefox fork) and IE, both. Then the same happened just now (with Google Public DNS). Once again I have changed to a different free DNS service (my ISP, unfortunately, does not provide IPv6 resolver addresses, only IPv4), and I fully expect that within the space of hours I will, once again, be unable to access my website without changing to the IPv6 addresses of another DNS service. I do not understand what is going on with this ...and, no, there is no DNSSEC configured for the site, yet.

Comment: I have also checked the site using dig and nslookup, both fine, and other, proxy or web-checker, sites; not to mention that the logs are not showing any problems. I managed to browse to the site not more than 5 minutes ago, but now all attempts (including by IP address) fail (server taking too long to respond), and that situation will persist until I change to a different DNS service, whilst OpenDNS and Google Public DNS will remain completely unusable.

Comment: Just found this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Resolv.conf, where it talks about **Hostname lookup delayed with IPv6**. I have just added _options single-request_ to my _resolv.conf_ and managed to get the website up and visible again using Google Public DNS. It just remains to be seen, now, whether or not it remains up and visible...

Answer (score 0):

After several tests, and several hours of my website remaining up and available to me (not just the rest of the internet!), I am inclined to think that the problem I was experiencing was, indeed, caused by my BIND nameserver trying to simultaneously return records from both IPv4 and IPv6 when I was trying to browse the site.

As stated on: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Resolv.conf, the solution given for **Hostname lookup delayed with IPv6**, that being adding *options single-request* to the *resolv.conf* file, does work (for me, at least).

**Note:** this amendment will occasionally be removed, especially following system updates. Use of the following, as the root user, should prevent this from happening, but may cause NetworkManager to produce errors:

**chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf** //to set the read-only attribute

**chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf** //to remove the read-only attribute

...followed by: *systemctl restart network.service*

Comment: If you've deliberately disabled all IPv4 connectivity on your network, it would have been useful to mention that...

Comment: That was not the case: I had to disable DHCP for both IPv4 and IPv6 because I could find no way of making DHCP respect IP addresses that had been allocated to the network adapters. The VLAN configuration was problematic, too. I had to re-enable DHCP on the IPv6 side, and I have left the IPv6 VLAN adapter configuration (on the Windows machine) set to automatic for IP address and DNS because it appears that those settings can be over-ridden by the Linux laptop adapter configurations.

Comment: To explain more clearly: the VLAN is configured on the router, but has to be enabled on the Windows PC driver interface. The result of this is that there are three adapters on the Windows machine, including one that influences the VLAN on the Linux laptop, which, in turn, can be over-ridden (if everything is set to automatic) by the Linux VLAN adapter configuration.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the use of _options single-request_, too. As I understand it, it is used in situations where there are both IPv4 **and** IPv6 glue records in place, to prevent a conflict caused by the DNS server returning records for both in which the website or service request simply times out or returns a _servfail_ or _server not found_ error.